# Parent - child sql query with in a single table

Tags: sql

I've a table:

```
Id | Name |  ParentID
```

I want to select records whose `parentid` not equal to zero, with parent record(parent record have `parentid = 0`, but some parent record don't have child record I want to skip them )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT child.Id,
       child.Name,
       child.ParentId,
       parent.Name as ParentName
FROM your_table child
JOIN your_table parent ON child.ParentId = parent.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this one:

```
select * from child c,parent p where c.ID=P.ParentID and c.ParentID !=0
```