# Create Sql subcategory table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have went to give interview today there is question that i didn't hear about, i wana know how to do this ... how to make this with query

create a single table that can hold up till n-level category's. create a table to expandable category tree given the following example . Now the table should be designed in such way that category level can be extended to as much as required .

```
                                  root
                                  /   \
                                 /     \
                               MEN      women------------
                               / \         /            |
                              /   \       Shirt&top     paints
                         shirt   trousers                /   \ 
                                                        /     \
                                                       /       \
                                                      /         \
                                                    trouser     Skirts and jeans
```

Comment: It's simple, did you heard about `parent_id` ? :) 1.Root.0, 2.MEN.1, 3.WOMEN.1, 4.SHIRT.2 ...

Comment: Please take a look over here I am sure this will be helpful to you http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35305/multiple-parents-and-multiple-children-in-product-categories

Comment: http://community.sitepoint.com/t/n-level-category-tree-using-php-and-mysql/4168/6

Comment: @LalitSharma ... 'single table'

Comment: it is something called `Recursive Relationship`. search on google web/images or refer link provided by @LalitSharma.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14832092/parent-child-sql-query-with-in-a-single-table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "cookbook" solution would be to have a parent id column pointing to a category id in a single table:

```
CREATE TABLE categories (
    category_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    parent_id INT REFERENCES category_id,
    name VARCHAR(100)
)
```

So, for the example given above:

```
INSERT INTO categories VALUES (1, null, 'root'),
(2, 1, 'Men'),
(3, 2, 'shirt'),
(4, 2, 'trousers'),
(5, 1, 'women'),
(6, 5, 'shirt & top'),
(7, 5, 'pants'),
(8, 7, 'trousers'),
(9, 7, 'skirts and jeans');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to implement that structure in a single table, you could store per row the following information:

1. id (primary key, category id)
2. parent_id (points to the parent category id)
3. category_name (textual representation of the category name)

So in your example, the data would be stored as such:

```
1 | 0 | root
2 | 1 | MEN
3 | 2 | shirt
4 | 2 | trousers
5 | 1 | women
6 | 5 | shirt & top
```

... and so on